# How do I write a function to display the student's record of the entered roll number

Tags: c++

We have to ask for info(roll no, name, course) of the students from the user. And display the input info. And lastly, have to add another function to ask for roll no. And that entered roll no's student info will be displayed. I am having trouble understanding how to solve the last part.

This is the code I did. I tried other ways but the code won't work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student{

    private:
        int rno ;
        string name ;
        string course ;
    public:
        Student(){
            // default
        }
        Student(int rno, string name, string course){
            this -> rno = rno;
            this -> name = name; 
            this -> course = course;
        }
        void displayMembers(){
            cout << "RNO : " << rno << "\tName : " << name << "\tCourse : " << course << endl;
        }
        // void searchRoll(){
        //     this -> rno = rno;
        // }
};

int main(){

    Student stu[2];
    int rno ;
    string name ;
    string course ;

    // ask info
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        cout << "Enter Roll Number : " ;
        cin >> rno;
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "Enter Name : " ;
        getline(cin, name);
        cout << "Enter Course Name : " ;
        getline(cin, course);
        stu[i] = Student(rno, name, course);
    }

    // display
    cout << "Enter Student Informations!" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        stu[i].displayMembers();
    }

    // search by rno
    // cout << "Enter Roll Number to Search : " ;
    // cin >> rno;
    // for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    //     stu[i].searchRoll();
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why can't your searchRoll or even simpler just in your last loop do stu[rno].displayMemers()

Comment: One student can't be responsible for searching through your array of students.

Comment: That is one powerful Student, where that one student has the entire student roll.  The hint is that objects should closely represent "real life" scenarios.  We know that a single Student shouldn't have the entire student roll.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a `searchRoll()` function in your `Student` class. You will want to add a getter for the `rno` member. Then, you could simply loop through the array and compare the entered value to the `rno` member of each item and stop when you get a match.